# MathJax Rendering SVG Format not proper in IE browser

Tags: html, svg

I am trying to Render SVG for the mathml. It looks fine on chrome , but in IE svg has additonal attributs to its tag How can we avoid these additional attributes being added. Please try to render below mathml as SVG in chrome and IE. You can see the difference in SVG tag which got generated (Attached scrrenshots in both browsers)
MathML used to render:

```html
"<math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"><mrow><mn style="font-family:inherit;font-style:inherit;" id="63201617503163">1</mn><mn style="font-family:inherit;font-style:inherit;" id="63201617503164">2</mn><mn style="font-family:inherit;font-style:inherit;" id="63201617503165">3</mn><mtable columnalign="right" align="baseline 2" rowspacing="0.0ex" id="63201617503166"><mtr><mtd><mrow><mn style="font-family:inherit;font-style:inherit;" id="63201617503167">1</mn><mn style="font-family:inherit;font-style:inherit;" id="63201617503168">2</mn><mn style="font-family:inherit;font-style:inherit;" id="63201617503169">3</mn></mrow></mtd></mtr><mtr><mtd><menclose notation="longdiv"><mrow><mn style="font-family:inherit;font-style:inherit;" id="63201617503170">1</mn><mn style="font-family:inherit;font-style:inherit;" id="63201617503171">2</mn><mn style="font-family:inherit;font-style:inherit;" id="63201617503172">3</mn><mn style="font-family:inherit;font-style:inherit;" id="63201617503173">4</mn><mn style="font-family:inherit;font-style:inherit;" id="63201617503174">5</mn></mrow></menclose></mtd></mtr><mtr><mtd><munder><mrow><mn style="font-family:inherit;font-style:inherit;" id="63201617503175">1</mn><mn style="font-family:inherit;font-style:inherit;" id="63201617503176">2</mn><mn style="font-family:inherit;font-style:inherit;" id="63201617503177">3</mn></mrow><mrow><mo>_</mo></mrow></munder><mphantom><mrow><mn>45</mn></mrow></mphantom></mtd></mtr><mtr><mtd><mrow><mn style="font-family:inherit;font-style:inherit;" id="63201617503178">1</mn><mn style="font-family:inherit;font-style:inherit;" id="63201617503179">2</mn><mn style="font-family:inherit;font-style:inherit;" id="63201617503180">3</mn></mrow></mtd></mtr></mtable></mrow></math>"
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi,Because of those additional attributes Allignment in IE browser is not proper.

Comment: Probably best you report it as a bug https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/issues